# How to lock a post or page

Tags: posts, password

How to lock a post or page from editing or deleting but can be viewed on site? I am not able to lock a post, I read several articles but can't find my answer.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`'wp_insert_post_data'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter to set the data being updated to the ones post has right now:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'prevent_post_edit', 99, 2);

prevent_post_edit ($data, $postarr) {
  if ( ! isset($postarr['ID']) || empty($postarr['ID']) ) return $data;
  if ( current_user_can('edit_files') ) return $data; // admin can edit posts
  // prevent the update only for post and pages, change this according to tour needs
  $prevent_types = array('post', 'page');
  if ( ! in_array($data['post_type'], $prevent_types) ) return data;
  // get the post how is before the update
  $old = get_post($postarr[ID]);
  return get_object_vars($old);
}
```

Comment: There was an error on original posted code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin.

> Users of any level can be elevated to read or edit content of your
>   choice. Restricted content can be withheld from users lacking a
>   content-specific role, regardless of their WP role.

**Edit**: Also there is [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) that has content-level pemissions.